# touchbar and keyboard brightness adjustment

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, touch-bar

Is there a way to manually control keyboard backlight with a MBP touchbar?

The same way the old F6 key was working on non touchbar laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, first expand the control strip by clicking on the arrow next to the 4 control buttons on the right (or 5 if you set it). Now there should be two icon similar to the one on the F5 and F6 key (unless you got rid of it in Keyboard Settings -> Customize Control Strip it should be there).

Comment: Thanks... I think it's time for me to see an ophthalmologist.